Document exchange or documents exchange?
Even the grammar correction logic here on the website is suggesting that "document exchange" is the correct one but could someone explain the reason for this?

... Also  "It is normal that the first or attributive noun of a sequence will be singular," says Geoffrey Leech. "Yet studies of recent English . . . have noted the apparently increasing variety of formations with a plural attributive noun" (Change in Contemporary English: A Grammatical Study, 2010).... Examples include "sports car," "women leaders," and "animal rights campaign." ' But the singular attributive noun is far more usual.
